# Rolling up data in Typescript

Tags: typescript

I have the following code I'm trying to run:

```
interface Datapoint {
    [key: string]: number
}

const props: Array<string> = ["a", "b", "c"]

const data: Array<Datapoint> = ...

const rolled_up: Datapoint = data.reduce(function(a: Array<Datapoint>, b: Array<Datapoint>){
  props.map(function(prop: string){
    a[prop] += b[prop]
  })
  return a
})
```

I want to roll up my data array into a single Datapoint, where the fields are added over the array for the given properties (`props`).

When I try and compile this, I get:

```
error TS7015: Element implicitly has an 'any' type because index expression is not of type 'number'.
```

on the line

```
a[prop] += b[prop]
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The types for the arguments to your `reduce()` function are wrong. Should be:

```
const rolled_up: Datapoint = data.reduce(function(a: Datapoint, b: Datapoint){
  props.map(function(prop: string){
    a[prop] += b[prop]
  })
  return a
})
```

Answer (score 0):

This issue was the types in my reduce function, they should have been:

```
function(a: Datapoint, b: Datapoint)
```